# In PHP when should you use isset?

Tags: php, isset

When should you use:

`if`(  `//following code`

1. `!isset($foo)`
2. `!($foo)`
3. `$foo == ""`
   )

Comment: Do you mean 'in which circumstances should you use isset', or 'where in this sequence should one use isset'?  Also, there should be `||` or `&&` between those conditions, correct?

Comment: The first one is a type comparison (against NULL and UNDEF), and the other two are boolean context comparisons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't use isset and the variable you're testing is undefined, you'll generate a warning. Additionally, there is a difference between something having never been set at all, and being set to an empty string, false, null or 0. Consider you're checking an array key and you just want to know if it's been created or not - and don't care about the value - if (!$a['key']) would return false if the key was 0, null or empty.

If you know the variable will be defined and the test only needs to know if the variable is non-false - that is 0, '', null, or false - then you can bypass isset.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you want to check if `$foo` exists, but don't care about it's value.
2. When you know `$foo` exists and want to make sure it evaluates as `false`.
3. Never, you should use [trim](http://www.php.net/trim) and [empty](http://www.php.net/empty) or [strlen](http://www.php.net/strlen) instead.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP type comparison tables](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 0):

isset verifies if a variable or array index has been set to something else than null.

isset($var) === false

$var= null;
isset($var) === false

$var= 1;
isset($var) === true

$var= '';
isset($var) === true

// Same goes for arrays
$array= array();
isset($array) === true
isset($array[0]) === false

Answer (score 0):

In the conditions for an  `if` statement, `isset` should go first if you need to check whether the variable exists. You can also use `empty` in certain cases, such as when you want to check if it's either undefined or loosely equal to null.

Using `isset` is useful to prevent warnings in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to specifically check to see if a variable is set (whether it actually contains anything or not), !empty() is always better to use than isset.

Answer (score -1):

1 : Is any value of the var $foo is set

```
function test($param = NULL){
  if(isset($param)){
    ....
  }
}
```

2 : check for boolean true/false ( also checks for empty string )

3 : check for empty string.

```
if(trim($_POST['name']) == ""){
   // throw error
}
```

Not amazing examples i know but hope they get the message across.

Comment: Example 2 won't work; `$var = false; isset($var);` returns true.

Comment: just to be clear the above are ways how the 3 ifs could be used

Comment: That wasn't the question - the question was when/why to use `isset`.

Comment: @Jimmy Sawczuk .. in all honesty the question is not that clear, so i take it that he wants to know in which situations the 3 different ifs should be used.